# Ports in URL - IIS7

Tags: url, iis-7, moodle, ports

I actually need to add a port number to url to access different applications. For example:

http:// moodle.somecollege.com:1000 --> Moodle1 --> C:/Moodle1

http:// moodle.somecollege.com:1001 --> Moodle2 --> C:/Moodle2

http:// moodle.somecollege.com:1002 --> Moodle3 --> C:/Moodle3

This works ok! But now, for some Moodle reason, I need to avoid using the port number to access each site. So, I would need to acces with something like this:

http:// moodle1.moodle.somecollege.com

http:// moodle2.moodle.somecollege.com

http:// moodle3.moodle.somecollege.com

Is there any tool in IIS7 to easily change the "url-with-port" to a url that doesn't require the port. At least explicitly.

Thanks in advance.

--
Angel

Answer (score 0):

Use host headers and change the port to 80. That way you will not need to explicitly provide the URL with Ports.